# Apache restrict file access to specific extensions, and allow directory index file to work also

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, indexing

I have been searching for a solution to this problem, but none of the suggestions seem to apply to my problem.

I have an apache webserver running with a few virtual sites, i manage them with webmin, and i am trying to secure the /var/www directory, which is the root of the site i am managing. What i would like is to have apache only serve php, html, jpg, css, js, gif and so on, common file types. That works fine, but my problem is that i have someone accessing the root directory http://example.com/ and apache is set up to use index.php in this case, with the the DirectoryIndex setting. This does not work, i get a 403 Forbidden error, if i put the full patch like http://example.com/index.php it works fine.

This is the apache config, for the site :

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/"
<Directory "/var/www/">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
<FilesMatch "\.*$">
deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(png|jpg|gif|css|php|html|js)$">
allow from all
</FilesMatch>

DirectoryIndex index.php
```

How would i go about allowing access to the index.php that is reached when not actually putting it in the url ?

Comment: Did you restart apache after the configuration update? Is there no htaccess in the root that overrules the directory index again?

Comment: Yes, everytime i change something i reload apache and clear my browser cache before testing again, and there is no .htaccess file in the root dir.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your files match patterns to:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(png|jpg|gif|css|php|html|js)$">
allow from all
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(?<!png|jpg|gif|css|php|html|js)$">
deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```