# limit uploaded files based on extensions in apache

Tags: apache, centos, redhat, httpd.conf

I have a site that has a place for upload files by I want to prevent users for upload files by .png and .gif files.
I test these config :

```
<FilesMatch "\.(png|gif)$">
allow from all
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(?<!png|gif)$">
deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

[Apache restrict file access to specific extensions, and allow directory index file to work also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897206/apache-restrict-file-access-to-specific-extensions-and-allow-directory-index-fi)

but still can upload these extensions in my site.
could you please help?