# How to deny access to specific document types in LAMP

Tags: php, apache, centos7, lamp

I am conducting a test run of my concept control web panel project on Centos7 using LAMP. However, I am experiencing a bit of a problem. When I visit http://mywebsiteurl.com/users.db rather than say **forbidden or display a blank page**. The browser auto downloads the .db file. How can I prevent this from happening. Is there a way to restrict access to files with a particular extension?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache restrict file access to specific extensions, and allow directory index file to work also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897206/apache-restrict-file-access-to-specific-extensions-and-allow-directory-index-fi)

Comment: Thanks CBroe, but no it doesn't answer my question. I want to edit httpd.conf so that when the url is typed into the browser, rather than auto download, a blank page an error page or a restriction of some sort will be displayed.

Comment: Forbidding HTTP access this way will trigger the error document that is configured for the 403 status code - so configure one of your choice then, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after hours of research, trial and error. I somehow managed to fix my problem using the solution found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5605110/18351396

I just changed the file extension to .db to suit my case.

Thanks everyone, especially CBroe.